# JPQ query Join on a LIst?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm in Spring Boot and I'm having a problem finding out how to write a query.
Basically i have those class

```
public Class Book{
  private long id
  private String title
  private List<Author> authors
...
}
```

```
public Class Author{
  private long id
  private String authorName
 
}
```

where authors can be a variable number of Author. I have a @ManyToMany and a @JoinTable between the 2 ids. Problems is: How can i write a method which takes one author's id and gives me all the books where he's present in the list? Do i need a query for it?

Comment: use native query

join between book and book_author

Comment: When in doubt, try a query. @Query("Select b from Book b join b.authors a where a.authorName = :authorName"). Otherwise, trial and error (just learning myself) on spring method naming findByAuthors_AuthorName might work, but I find letting it pick the query based on the name more pain then it is worth (to me).